# How many unique IPs viewed a question?

Tags: support

On the main board, the question list shows how many views each question has had.  However, is there a place to see how many unique IPs have accessed the question, and when it was accessed?

I posted my question about the 1940 census comment to Facebook, so it would be interesting to see how many people are accessing the question on StackExchange from that post.

Also, the Announcer badge requires a certain number of unique IPs to view the post from the share, so I'm curious if there's a way to view the current number ;)

Comment: I've never seen anyway to do this.

Comment: Well, I just got the Announcer badge -- so apparently at least 25 people have viewed it :)  Interestingly, I'm the first one here to get the Announcer badge!  We should all post a link to our questions on Facebook when we can... it's a great way to get the word out about Genealogy.SE

Comment: Congrats! If you really want to see the running total, make this a feature request. The devs usually get back pretty quickly on those. Wait a minute. Here's a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/192187 Not much happening.